# Why would a shul face the wrong direction for davening?

Tags: tefilla

Does anybody have an idea why the Chaim Berlin Alumni Minyan in Brooklyn  (Ave I and East 13th Street) has a shul in which the Aron Kodesh is facing almost completely opposite from Mizrach and the mispallilim daven in the wrong direction? As far as I know, it is the only shul in Brooklyn that faces the wrong direction.

Comment: Good question, +1! I've seen many shuls in the US where the aron faces NE or SE, or even north or west, but I don't know if I've ever seen one facing due west.

Comment: @DoubleAA. I read that question and answer before posting this one. It's not a duplicate. I'm asking about this specific shul and the question is based on issues not in any way similar to those Manhattan shuls.